# SPProductVersionJobDefinition throws Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: 2013, central-administration, upgrade, timer-jobs

I just finished Sp1 Upgrade in a Sp2013 Server Dev Environment. Going through the Windows Event log i discovered following error:

> The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProductVersionJobDefinition (ID 84a7a060-e495-4582-9bd1-b3767841446d) threw an exception. More information is included below.
>
> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

ID referenced in the error message is of Job title "Product Version Job" running in Web front end server. Under Central Admin TimerJobHistory Job is listed as failed Job at 12:35 Am .

Sharepoint Diagnostic Logs Says Below at the time of the incident

```
 Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-upgrade-sites). Parent No  ac731a87-3b28-40f1-9f01-04cd45342bd6
10/16/2014 00:45:59.48  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x25FC)                       0x291C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job job-upgrade-sites    3b97c29c-9e13-a0bb-f8e8-f67517c88aa7
10/16/2014 00:45:59.59  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x25FC)                       0x291C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-upgrade-sites). Execution Time=112.118998364317  3b97c29c-9e13-a0bb-f8e8-f67517c88aa7
10/16/2014 00:45:59.62  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x25FC)                       0x2B34  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         ajy66   High        10/16/2014 00:45:59.62 OWSTIMER (0x25FC) 0x2B34 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPWebApplicationSequence ajy66 DEBUG Adding a iis web site object with instance Id = [1259120565] 2c97c29c-4ea2-a0bb-f8e8-f9cfdcf84194    2c97c29c-4ea2-a0bb-f8e8-f9cfdcf84194
10/16/2014 00:45:59.62  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x25FC)                       0x2B34  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         ajyw6   High        10/16/2014 00:45:59.62 OWSTIMER (0x25FC) 0x2B34 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPHierarchyManager ajyw6 DEBUG [SPTree Value=SPWebApplication Name=SharePoint - communitiesdev44...] added to dependency cache by lookup 2c97c29c-4ea2-a0bb-f8e8-f9cfdcf84194 2c97c29c-4ea2-a0bb-f8e8-f9cfdcf84194
10/16/2014 00:45:59.65  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x25FC)                       0x2B34  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           6398    Critical    The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProductVersionJobDefinition (ID 84a7a060-e495-4582-9bd1-b3767841446d) threw an exception. More information is included below.  Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.   2c97c29c-4ea2-a0bb-f8e8-f9cfdcf84194
10/16/2014 00:45:59.68  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x25FC)                       0x2B34  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           72ae    Unexpected  Exception stack trace:    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.DetectLocalUpgradeStatus()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.DetectLocalProductVersions(SPProductVersions prodVer)     at Microsoft... 2c97c29c-4ea2-a0bb-f8e8-f9cfdcf84194
10/16/2014 00:45:59.68* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x25FC)                       0x2B34  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           72ae    Unexpected  ....SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.UpdateProductInfoInDatabase(Guid serverGuid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProductVersionJobDefinition.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result) 2c97c29c-4ea2-a0bb-f8e8-f9cfdcf84194
10/16/2014 00:45:59.68  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x25FC)                       0x2B34  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-admin-product-version). Execution Time=59371.9824726327  2c97c29c-4ea2-a0bb-f8e8-f9cfdcf84194
```

We havent experienced any catastropic failure due to this, but i am cautious if my recent upgrade completed successfully.

What do you think SharePoint Experts?

Some Info about my environment:

- Configuration database version: 15.0.4569.1000
- Database Upgrade Status: "No action required" on all dbs
- Patch Status: 15.0.4571.1502 among all servers in Farm.

Comment: Did anyone else have any comments on this - we are seeing this sporadically occur in a production farm on different servers with little consistency

Answer (score 2):

Probably this link will help you:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7b3389f0-c0e2-468b-9c26-611af8402a6b/the-execute-method-of-job-definition?forum=projserv2010setup

It suggests that either removing and then re-adding the farm or running:

```
Get-SPProduct –local
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)